# Write ZipEntry Data To String

Tags: java, android

I have retrieved a zip entry from a zip file like so.

```
InputStream input = params[0];
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(input);

ZipEntry entry;
try {
    while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry())!= null) {

    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This works fine and its getting my `ZipEntry` no problem.

**My Question**

How can I get the contents of these `ZipEntries` into a String as they are xml and csv files.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you have to read from the `ZipInputStream`:

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int read = 0;
ZipEntry entry;
while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry())!= null) {
      while ((read = zis.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {
           s.append(new String(buffer, 0, read));
      }
}
```

When you exit from the inner `while` save the `StringBuilder` content, and reset it.

Comment: blackbelt to the rescue again. Thank you my friend

Comment: This approach will break unicode characters, which are two bytes or more.

Answer (score 5):

With defined encoding (e.g. UTF-8) and without creation of Strings:

```
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

try (
  ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(input, UTF_8); 
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
) {
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
  int read = 0;
  ZipEntry entry;
  while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry()) != null)
    while ((read = zis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0)
      baos.write(buffer, 0, read);
  String content = baos.toString(UTF_8.name());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the approach, which does not break Unicode characters:

```
final ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(content));
final InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(zis);
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
final char[] buffer = new char[1024];

while (isr.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length) != -1) {
    sb.append(new String(buffer));
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Could you please describe in which way the version of @Blackbelt will break Unicode? His version reads until there is nothing left (i.e. all parts of Unicode I'd expect to be there), while your version always adds the whole buffer, creating a final String which is much longer than entry.getSize()

Comment: Ok, I now see that you use char[] instead of byte[]. I'd suggest to make this more visible in the answer, and also only add as much of the buffer as you're read. Currently your resulting string gets rounded up to the buffer size.

Answer (score 1):

I would use apache's IOUtils

```
ZipEntry entry;
InputStream input = params[0];
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(input);

try {
  while ((entry = zis.getNextEntry())!= null) {
    String entryAsString = IOUtils.toString(zis, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
IOUtils.closeQuietly(zis);
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin version but can be used in Java as well

```
val zipInputStream = ZipInputStream(inStream)
var zipEntry = zipInputStream.nextEntry
while(zipEntry != null) {
    println("Name of file : " + zipEntry.name)
    val fileContent = String(zipInputStream.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    println("File content : $fileContent")
    zipEntry = zipInputStream.nextEntry
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the file is known to be small, you can just use `zis.readAllBytes()` and construct a `new String` with it.

For instance, in unit testing a file that only contains 1 xml file, I wrote :

```java
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(yourZipFile));
ZipEntry zipEntry = zis.getNextEntry();
String xmlString = new String(zis.readAllBytes());
zis.closeEntry();
zis.close();
```

The important thing to remember is to first read the entry (and probably use this information to get the file name) and then read the file content because   in a zip file, the data is organized as a succession of (file entry then file data).

You can refer to [Baeldung's Zipping and Unzipping in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-compress-and-uncompress) for more details and examples with multiple files in the zip.